# GAE - Java 11 migration - why are warmup requests not guaranteed to be called anymore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, java-11

In Java 8 Google App Engine there are ServletContextListener to allow you to run some start up code. In Java 11 the recommended way is [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/configuring-warmup-requests). It states that:

> Note that **warmup requests are not guaranteed to be called**. In some
> situations loading requests are sent instead: for example, if the
> instance is the first one being started up, or if there is a steep
> ramp-up in traffic. However, there will be a "best effort" attempt to
> send requests to already warmed-up instances if warmup requests are
> enabled.

This is a bit of a problem for me because I have dependencies that need to be initialized before they can be run successfully.

If the warmup request is not guaranteed to run anymore, my code will run into a runtime error.

Is there solution that can 100% run some warmup initialization code with the Java 11 Google App Engine environment?

Comment: Are you intending to migrate to Java 11? For any particular reason? I'm asking because in your conversation with Mr Blaquiere you mention Cloud Endpoints and my understanding is that [Cloud Endpoints only supports Java 8](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks#limitations). Maybe for this reason? Perhaps they're still adapting Cloud Endpoints to this new limitation from Java 11?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call the load dependencies function on warmup request and standard request. To prevent the multiple load, you can use a global variables; the singleton pattern in short. Here a pseudo code

```
Boolean globalLoading = false;

public void warmup(){
  loadDependencies();
}

public void loadDependencies(){
   if (globalLoading) return;
   <TODO>
   globalLoading = true;
}

public String myGetEndpoint(params){
  loadDependencies();
  <TODO>
}
....
```

Like that, you are sure your dependencies are loaded on any request, in best effort in the warmup to not impact the 1st request serving latency, but in the worse case, the latency is bad but your instance is OK.

Comment: What do you mean and for "standard" requests? You mean call `loadDependencies()` before each and every api method? There are hundreds of those in my case - doesn't seem very clean to do that.

Comment: I don't know your framework, but usually, you can plug an interceptor on the request processing. You can do that at this stage to have a mutualized call. And no worries about the overhead, it's only one IF when the libraries are already loaded. (about 10 cpu cycles)

Comment: I'm using Cloud Endpoints. Does what you say apply to it?

Comment: You use Cloud Endpoint framework, right? I'm sure there is an interceptor chain that you can override. But you might need to dig into the source code to see where.